# CKEditor not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

This is the code i've implemented so far

```
<div class="CommentBox" style="display: none;">
   <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ObjComment.Description, new { @id = "txtComment", @class = "clsCKEditor" })
   </div>
</div>
```

And the JQuery code is as follows:

```
 $("#btnComment").click(function () {        
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[txtComment];
        if (CKEDITOR) {
            if (CKEDITOR.instances.txtComment) {
                CKEDITOR.instances.txtComment.destroy();
            }
        }
        $("#txtComment").val('');
        CKEDITOR.replace('txtComment', { uiColor: '#D8D8D8' });

        CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;
        $(".CommentBox").show("slow");           
    });
```

Here, txtComment is an id of the textarea which i'm using as an Editor. On click of the button, the editor will be generated and the div containing this editor will show up.

This is working perfectly as expected in Chrome and Firefox. However,its giving error in IE11 at this line:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[txtComment];**'txtComment' is undefined**
```

Ami missing something? Would you please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove that line because you're not using the `editor` variable at all, so that line is useless.

The problem with that line is that you're trying to use a variable named `txtComment`, instead of a string `"txtComment"`

Comment: Changing txtComment to "txtComment" worked. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I had some javascript and Ajax errors with IE11 and by putting this in the Head section of your page you are telling IE11 to go into compatibility mode.  This solved my problem.